# How to bundle storage permission with external storage manager permission

Tags: android, android-11

I am working on a files app and after targeting to API-30, I need permissions for not just media store permission (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`), but also need to be an external storage manager (`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`). In order to do so, I have to show 2 different system dialogs to the customer. The first one is the media store permissions dialog:

[image: Storage Permission Dialog]

```
/* Code to show this permission */
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);
```

And then I have to show the following one to get external storage manager permissions:

[image]

```
/* Code to show this permission */
final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
final Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Is there something in the android system that shows user a dialog that bundles all the storage permissions together, or any android system flow that can be launched that guides user throughout both permission together? Having two different flows seems like a terrible amount of redundant logic that needs to be owned by apps. I was not able to find something like that, so asking here if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something in the android system that shows user a dialog that bundles all the storage permissions together

Not in terms of `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, as that is not a runtime permission that you handle via `requestPermissions()`. `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` can be requested together using `requestPermissions()`.

> or any android system flow that can be launched that guides user throughout both permission together?

No, sorry.

Note that I have not tried holding `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` without `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Perhaps `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not needed if you hold `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) suggests that this might be the case.

> Having two different flows seems like a terrible amount of redundant logic that needs to be owned by apps

Very few apps should be asking the user to grant `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. And apparently Google really wants users to think through whether they should be granting that permission to your app.

Comment: If I only ask for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, I don't get any permission. In the app info, I see `No Permission Requested` under permissions section. We have conducted a thorough analysis on this and seems like we need both of these permissions.

Comment: @ABS: "In the app info, I see No Permission Requested under permissions section" -- I would expect that. I was more interested if you could actually write to files. If that is not supported unless you hold both permissions, then I linked to a typically confusing bit of Android developer documentation.

Comment: Oh, thats a good point, I'll test it out. Thanks!